# remover un elemento del DOM y no cargarlo de nuevo al refrescar la pagina

Tags: html, jquery

Estoy removiendo un div con `remove()`, pero necesito eliminarlo por completo, me explico al eliminarlo con remove lo elimina pero si actualizo el navegador o refresco la pagina se muestra nuevamente necesito eliminarlo y que ya no cargue si se refresca la pagina, no se si se peude hacer almacenado en una variable el valor, o usando cokies no estoy seguro gracias por la ayuda.

```
$('.midiv').remove();
```

Answer (score 2):

realmente no entiendo bien para que quieres hacerlo, pero como dices puedes hacerlo almacenando una variable que perdure aunque recargues la pagina, por ello usar **localStorage** o **sessionStorage** de la siguiente forma

```
$( document ).ready(() => {
    let quitarDiv = sessionStorage.getItem('quitarDiv');
    if (quitarDiv !== true) { // puede devolver undefined si no esta seteada
      $(".midiv").remove();
    }
});


function onQuitarDiv() {
  sessionStorage.setItem('quitarDiv', true);
  $(".midiv").remove()
}
```

No puedo ponerte un ejemplo practico porque el sandobox de stackoverflow no deja trabajar con ninguno de los dos.